# how can i apply group css on HTML Elements

Tags: html, css

I want to try using group CSS like is `.groupA{ .text1{ color: bule; } }` is this correct way to using CSS like this.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="groupA">
<div class="text1">bla bla bla bla</div>
<div class="text1">bla bla bla bla</div>
<div class="text1">bla bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

I want this format to using CSS in grouping.

```
.groupA{
  .text1{
    color:blue;
  }
 }

 .groupB{
    .text1{
     color:yellow;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just use `.groupA .text1` or just `.group>*`.

Comment: An other way to using CSS in grouping

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS child selectors:

```
.groupA .text1 /* all elements with class text1 somewhere under groupA */ {
  /* … */
}
```

Alternatives:

```
.groupA > .text1 /* all elements with class text1 directly under groupA */
.groupA > * /* any elements directly under groupA */
.groupA * /* any elements somewhere under groupA */
```

With the last two you don’t need to specify `class="text1"` everywhere.

Comment: Props for listing the other selectors. Since the OP appears have to have only a passing knowledge of CSS, it would be prudent to point out that your first example one would arguably be considered the most common and - more importantly - *most flexible and performative*  option.

Comment: you are right grouping css is only in `SCSS` thanks brother

Answer (score 0):

Actually class can be used at multiple locations. ID is used for unique representation. You can write the code like you did, but I suggest using groups as ID's rather than classes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="groupA">
<div class="text1">bla bla bla bla</div>
<div class="text1">bla bla bla bla</div>
<div class="text1">bla bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#groupA .text1{
    color:blue;
}

#groupB .text1{
     color:yellow;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to group the styling for your selectors (in this case the selectors are your DIVs), you should use a syntax like this:

```
.groupA, .text1 {
    color: #ffffff; 
    align: right;
}
```

This is grouping. But do note that everything inside .groupA is going to inherit groupA's attributes, so you do not need the .text1 class, unless you want certain styling of DIVs *within* .groupA to be styled differently. In that case, you might want each of your DIVs to have a different block of CSS code.